# \ifcommandkey is printing values despite the key having no value

Tags: latex3

I am a complete begineer to latex.

I have a command like below which is supposed to print if the key consists of a value. However, when I do not pass the key `coursework`, it still prints 'Relevant coursework:' Whereas it should have printed nothing.

```
--test.cls--

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2023/03/18 v0.1 Resume class]
\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

% set document margins
\usepackage[left=0.5 in,top=0.4in,right=0.5in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{keycommand}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=black,
}

% Load the fontspec package to set the font
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} % Load the Helvetica font
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set the default font family to sans-serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use the T1 font encoding to ensure proper character rendering

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\education}{
    \textbf{\MakeUppercase{Education}}
    \vspace{0.4em}
    \hrule
    \vspace{-0.3em}
}

\newkeycommand{\educationItem}[university,college,program,graduation,grade,coursework]{
    {\bfseries \commandkey{program}} \hfill {Graduating \commandkey{graduation}} \\
    {\commandkey{university}} \hfill \ifcommandkey{grade}{\commandkey{grade}}{} \\
    \ifcommandkey{college}{\commandkey{college}}{} \\
    \ifcommandkey{coursework}{ Relevant coursework: \commandkey{coursework}}{}
}

--main.tex--

\documentclass{test} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\begin{document}

\education{
    \educationItem[
        university=Boston University{,} Boston,
        graduation=May 2020,
        grade=3.82 GPA,
        college=The Community College,
        program=B.S.E.{,} Mechanical Engineering,
        coursework=Hardware Design Languages and Programmable Logic{,} Advanced Excel in Business
    ]
    \educationItem[
        university=California University{,} California,
        college=The Honors College,
        graduation=May 2020,
        program=B.S.E.{,} Mechanical Engineering,
    ]
}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide the complete code that we can compile.

Comment: Apologies. Edited the description.

Answer (score 3):

The `\ifcommandkey` macro is broken (it could actually work if it did one more step of expansion -- but it seems like there are several bugs in the package in which one step of expansion is missing).

If you put the following in your preamble (or class) you could fix your usages of `\ifcommandkey`:

```
\begingroup
\lccode`\_=`\/
\lowercase{%
\endgroup
%% copied from commandkey.sty version 2010/04/27 v3.1415 but altered to make it
%% actually work
\renewcommand*\ifcommandkey[1]{\csname @%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter
   \kcmd@nbk\commandkey{#1}__{first}{second}__%
   oftwo\endcsname}
}
```

But I suggest you use a different package (disclaimer: I'm the author of the different package suggested below).

`expkv-cs` provides a similar interface (not the same, but similar enough). With it you don't get some command like `\ifkeycommand`, but you can build something which is more flexible than that using secondary keys (keys that you can't access via `\ekvcValue`, but which can alter the primary keys). In the following I use that to augment the key values by the formatting instruction that's only necessary if the key was used.

**`.cls-file`**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2023/03/18 v0.1 Resume class]
\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

% set document margins
\RequirePackage[left=0.5 in,top=0.4in,right=0.5in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\RequirePackage{xstring}

% Load the fontspec package to set the font
\RequirePackage[scaled]{helvet} % Load the Helvetica font
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set the default font family to sans-serif
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use the T1 font encoding to ensure proper character rendering

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\education}{%
    \textbf{\MakeUppercase{Education}}
    \vspace{0.4em}
    \hrule
    \vspace{-0.3em}
}

\RequirePackage{expkv-cs}
\ekvcHash\educationItem
  {%
     university          = {}
    ,program             = {}
    ,graduation          = {}
    ,grade               = {}
    ,college-internal    = {}
    ,coursework-internal = {}
  }
  {%
    \par\noindent
    {\bfseries\ekvcValue{program}{#1}}\hfill Graduating \ekvcValue{graduation}{#1}\\
    \ekvcValue{university}{#1}\hfill\ekvcValue{grade}{#1}% if empty doesn't hurt
    \ekvcValue{college-internal}{#1}%
    \ekvcValue{coursework-internal}{#1}%
  }
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\educationItem
  {%
     meta college    = {college-internal    = {\\#1}}
    ,meta coursework = {coursework-internal = {\\Relevant coursework: #1}}
  }

\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=black,
}
```

**`.tex-file:`**

The argument of `\educationItem` is now a mandatory argument (because it really isn't optional in the first place, and with a mandatory arguments things are just faster and more stable -- if you want an optional argument for now you need to wrap a macro created with `expkv-cs` inside a macro that grabs the optional argument for it and forwards it as a mandatory argument).

```
\documentclass{test} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\begin{document}

\education{
    \educationItem{
        university=Boston University{,} Boston,
        graduation=May 2020,
        grade=3.82 GPA,
        college=The Community College,
        program=B.S.E.{,} Mechanical Engineering,
        coursework=Hardware Design Languages and Programmable Logic{,} Advanced Excel in Business
    }
    \educationItem{
        university=California University{,} California,
        college=The Honors College,
        graduation=May 2020,
        program=B.S.E.{,} Mechanical Engineering,
    }
}

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]